# Chrome Extension using the site's loaded jQuery instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to use the jQuery instance that is loaded by the site in my extension?
I know I can include my own in the manifest file, however that is a seperate instance and therefore I cannot hook into global events of their instance! :)

Thanks!

Comment: No. You can't. A Chrome extension has no access to the page's variable's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't. A Chrome extension has no access to the page's variables.

Here's a quote [from the docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html):

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They **cannot**:
>
> 1. Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)
> 2. Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
> 3. **Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts**

Comment: right. Okay, I guess i'm just going to add my script to their body and hack it that way.

Comment: @Setheron - Why wouldn't you use your own instance of jQuery?

Comment: I need to attach global event handler to see when they make ajax calls.